# Euler formula, polyhedron with a hole

Tags: general-topology, geometry, geometric-topology, polyhedra

[image]I'd like to ask help for this question. I know that I need to have a little more concept on what kind of polyhedra that Euler's formula is valid.

Choose the false alternative:

a) F = 12
b) V = 20
c) E = 30
d) Euler's formula F + V - E = 2 applies
e) All above are true

Actually, by looking at this picture we can conclude that E is correct, since all of them seem to be true. However, shouldn't this formula be F + V - E = -2, since the genus is 2 ?

Comment: They must have made a typo.

Comment: If one among a-d is false, then e is false too. But if a-d are all true, then e) is true and can't be a "false alternative".

Comment: Actually in this exam it is understood that the "False" is valid for letters a-d. We should not interpret this so logically for letter e. The question is to be understood as: Choose the false alternative among a-d or e if all of them are true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of faces is listed as 12.  There are ten vertical faces and two "horizontal" faces (namely, top level and bottom level of the polyhedron).  However, the latter pair are not admissible as *faces* because a face has to be a convex polygon for the formula to apply.

Comment: So, they want the falsa alternative. Should it be D ?

Comment: Depends on how you define a face.

Answer (score -1):

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_with_holes#In_polyhedra

$\chi =V-E+F-\text{holes}=2(1-g)$

$V=20, E=30, F=12, H=4$ (2 faces each with 2 holes)

$\chi=20-30+12-4=-2=2(1-g)
\implies g=2$ so it's $2$-holed polyhedron.